# Magento second header

Tags: magento, header

I have a Magento store with two separate headers.  Let's say out of 20 pages 15 use header.phtml  and 5 use headerGreen.phtml.  I've already created my custom layout module however I can't seem to get the new header to appear on select pages.  The new headerGreen.phtml file has been created as well.  The issue lies when I try to call the new header in the newly created layout page.

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('headerGreen') ?>
```

I dont think I've added it correctly to the local.xml and was hoping someone could help.

```
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
          <block type="core/template" name="header" template="page/headerGreen.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `getChildHtml` is expecting you to send a name of a child in the layout as first parameter

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php` defines it :

```
/**
 * Retrieve child block HTML
 *
 * @param   string $name
 * @param   boolean $useCache
 * @param   boolean $sorted
 * @return  string
 */
public function getChildHtml($name = '', $useCache = true, $sorted = false)
{
    // the code is does not really matter here
}
```

So based on your layout you should actually do

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
```

Because header is the name attribute in this xml node of your layout :

```
<block type="core/template" name="header" template="page/headerGreen.phtml" />
```

As said in the comments, your layout is also looking strange because you are actually telling that your new header is going to be a child of the current header.

Two thinks you can do :

Use the powerfulness of the **action** nodes :

```
<default>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/headerGreen.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Or redefine the whole header block

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="header" as="header" template="page/headerGreen.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: But when I do that it shows the old header.  I want it to show the new header I just created called headerGreen.phtml

<block type="core/template" name="headerGreen" template="page/headerGreen.phtml" />

This does not work eithor

Comment: Because you actually got that wrong and you said that your "green header" was supposed to be a child of the "normal" header by nesting your xml node in a reference of a block called header. Updating my answer now.

Comment: Both suggestions made the header disappear no matter what layout I was using.

Comment: Did you changed to `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>` also ? And where are you doing this line of php by the way ?

Comment: yes it was changed to 'header'.  This code lies right underneath <div class="page" in the new layout just as it should I assume.

Comment: Next question then : what is the full path of `headerGreen.phtml` ?

Comment: It's in template/page/headerGreen.phtml